# Celery tries to import the broker URL as a module?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, celery

I recently added Celery to my back end but i got this weird error below

```
[2017-10-25 21:41:37,142: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ImportError('No module named myredisserverip.com',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 115, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 143, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 158, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 221, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1183, in backend
    return self._get_backend()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 901, in _get_backend
    self.loader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 66, in by_url
    return by_name(backend, loader), url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 46, in by_name
    cls = symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named myredisserverip.com
```

My config.py looks like this

```
class BaseConfig(object):
    """ A base configuration of the app """

    DEBUG = False
    SERVER_NAME = "my-production-ip"
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET']
    BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['SQL_PRODUCTION']
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['CELERY_BROKER_PROD']
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND_PROD']
    DATABASE_CONNECT_OPTIONS = {}
    THREADS_PER_PAGE = 2
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    CSRF_SESSION_KEY = "secret"
    MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
    MAIL_PORT = 465
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True
    MAIL_USE_TSL = False
    MAIL_USERNAME = "blabla"
    MAIL_PASSWORD = "pwd"
```

CELERY_BROKER_PROD and CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND are both the same and they contain the URL of the redis instance im running on amazon AWS. When i try to run

```
celery worker -A app.celery
```

from within my project directory i get this error, what is happening?

The way i setup celery is this

```
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you confirm what the values of CELERY_BROKER_PROD and CELERY_RESULTS_BACKEND are? 
It seems that you have defined this as myredisserverip.com, however according to the celery docs, redis server should be defined as:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:password@host:port/db'
```

as per the documentation here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#redis-backend-settings

For the broker_url you need to define the transport, documentation on this can be found here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#broker-url

Is the issue that you are missing the transport, ie the redis:// prefix in your environment variables?

Comment: I think you are right, maybe I used url instead of redis url, I will check it and let you know, thanks for answering and providing those links